# How to insert record in database on button click in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to insert a `true` value in data base on button click without using forms or form helper. I want simple method when I click on button then a `true` value will be stored in database using Ruby on Rails. How can I do this. I am not using a check box or radio button. I am using a button.

Here is the Migration File.

```
class CreateNewTableNotification < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|

      t.boolean :notify
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

*Also would better use REST routes instead of `'/notification/mark/your_id'`, that used in code bellow only as an example*

```
#view
<%= link_to '/notification/mark/your_id', remote: true do %>
  <button>Your button name</button>
<% end %>


#route.rb
get '/notification/mark/:id', to: 'notification#mark'

#notification controller
def mark
  Notification.find(params[:id]).update(notify: true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render status: 200 }
  end
end
```

Comment: If you don't mind a form wrapper the the view could also be done with [`#button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which is probably cleaner. `<%= button_to 'Your button name', '/notification/mark/your_id', remote: true, method: :get %>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to add the true/false logic to your existing :notification table? If so,

you have to run:

```
rails g migration AddCheckToNotifications check:boolean
```

inside your migration file, add to the boolean a default state:

```
 t.boolean :notify, default: false
```

now there is no 'real' way of toggling your boolean without a form. You normally would always like to create a form in order to be able to talk to your database.

Now since i don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish, i assume that a method that triggers your boolean is the best solution. So first, create inside your notifications controller a new method:

```
  def toggle_check
    @notification = Notification.find(params[:notification_id])
    if @notification.check == false
      @check = @notification.update(check: true)
    else
      @check = @notification.update(check: false)
    end
    redirect_to @notification
  end
```

Now you need to specify a special route for your method, in routes.rb create a new path like so:

```
resources :notifications do
    collection do
      get :toggle_check
    end
  end
```

Now the last step is to create a link that will call the path and the controller with the toggle method:

```
 <%= link_to "Check Toggle", :controller => :notifications, :action => :toggle_check, notification_id: @notification.id %>
```

Edit: This works now just fine! You don't even need a seperate route for a false statement, the method checks automatically if your boolean is true or false. Just add a

```
<%= @notification.check %>
```

to your show.html.erb file and you'll see that true/false will be changed whenever you click the link.

Heres a small example of it on my GitHub:

[Click](https://github.com/Prometheus88/ToggleCheckRails)

Let me know if this helped you!

Greetings!

Comment: yes i exactly want this that you did..but the problem is i want button click not check box..simply click on the button and the value is stored true..and when again click on button its value will be false...simple example like play/pause button in media player.when click on the button it play when we click again on the button it will pause it..

Comment: Have you checked out my project? There is no check box. Download the GitHub project i made, you have a button on it and whenever you click the button it becomes true/false. The code shown above does exactly that, WITHOUT a check box. Greetings!